# SQL SELECT and UPDATE Returns Different Result

Tags: sql

I probably need your help on this...
I have the following MySQL Query :

```
SELECT * FROM dbName1.Prospects A
LEFT JOIN dbName2.inbox B ON 
          substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 2) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
          substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 3) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
          substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 4) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) 
LEFT JOIN dbName1.User C ON A.Username = C.Username
WHERE B.TextDecoded IS NOT NULL
AND substring(B.SenderNumber,1,1) = '+'
AND B.NotificationFlag = '0'
```

which return 125 result...
But when I tried to update using the same query, it returns only 45 result updated...
The update query is :

```
UPDATE dbName1.Prospects A
LEFT JOIN dbName2 B ON 
            substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 2) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
            substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 3) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
            substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 4) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) 
LEFT JOIN dbName1.User C ON A.Username = C.Username
SET B.NotificationFlag = '1'
WHERE B.TextDecoded IS NOT NULL
AND substring(B.SenderNumber,1,1) = '+'
AND B.NotificationFlag = '0'
```

Did I do anything wrong on UPDATE query?

Many thanks for your help...

Comment: dbName2.inbox in the select is dbName2 in the update ! is this right?

Comment: are you sure it is a 1x1 join and not nxm ? Try select distinct dbname1.prospects(whatever the primary key is ) instead of * in first query

Comment: In Updates Check , Only 45 values might be changed other values might be the same as your update value. So it is showing 45 Updates

Comment: There is a difference between your first LEFT JOIN's as @TwoMore said in his comment.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the same statement, in your case the 2nd line is different in both statements:

In Select statement it is:

```
LEFT JOIN dbName2.inbox B ON
```

In Update statement it is:

```
LEFT JOIN dbName2 B ON
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this query to check real number of records from table B were joined.

```
Select distinct B.some_unique_field from dbName2.inbox B
Left Join dbName1.Prospects A ON 
          substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 2) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
          substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 3) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
          substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 4) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) 
WHERE B.TextDecoded IS NOT NULL
AND substring(B.SenderNumber,1,1) = '+'
AND B.NotificationFlag = '0';
```

Hope my query is correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Your select doesn't match the udpate since you're doing an update on b so basicaly it cuts down to `a JOIN b` and the select is `a LEFT JOIN b LEFT JOIN C`. Also more than one row in A can match a row in B so you can get more results than distinct rows in B. Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.ID FROM dbName1.Prospects A
JOIN dbName2.inbox B ON 
substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 2) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 3) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) OR 
substring(A.ProspectCellPhone, 4) = substring(B.SenderNumber, 4) 
WHERE B.TextDecoded IS NOT NULL
AND substring(B.SenderNumber,1,1) = '+'
AND B.NotificationFlag = '0'
```